# Jquery/Javascript Add class if X class is not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new here, sorry if I do some mistake with this question.
I have a HTML code.

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="one">hit me</a>
```

with this function i can add class `two` in class `one`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#foo').click(function(){
            $('.one').toggleClass('two'); 
        });
    });
```

but how if I want to add class `two` if class `two` is not exist and do other function if class `two` is exist?
maybe like this,

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="one">hit me</a>
```

i klik `hit me` and jquery is add class `two`,

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="one two">hit me</a>
```

but when I klick `hit me` again, class `two` is not removed and because class is exist, i create other function based on class two is exist.

lets say like this,

i klik `hit me`

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="one">hit me</a>
    <div id="blah" class=""*>lorem</div>
```

then

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="one two">hit me</a>
<div id="blah" class=""*>lorem</div>
```

and klik `hit me` again.

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="one two">hit me</a>
<div id="foo" class="blah2">lorem</div>
```

can you give me code or google suggest keyword or link, because I confused what i must search first.

thanks for adv,
sorry for my Grammer, i cant speak/write English well, if any wrong grammer or language please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method and you're examples:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#foo').click(function(){

      if ($(this).hasClass('two')) {
          $('#blah').addClass('blah2'); 
      } else {
          $(this).addClass('two'); 
      }

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks man, i'll try this first, because i dont know much about jquery/javascript, your example is looks like what i want, so i'll try it :)

Comment: your script is work, for dummy I change `$('#blah').addClass('blah2'); ` to `$('#blah').toggleClass('blah2'); ` .

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#foo').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('two')) {
            doSomething();
        } else {      
            $('.one').addClass('two'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm a little confused as to what exactly you want to do, but I think you need to look into `.hasClass()` for starters.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#foo').click(function(){
            if ($('.one').hasClass('two')) {
                // do stuff you want to do if element already has class "two"
            }
            else {
                // do stuff if it doesnt already have class "two"
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: yap, i cunfused too, because i cant speak/write englist well so i confuse how to explain what i mean. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing at your exact needs, but I hope that my assumptions weren't too far off base.

Given HTML like this:

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="one">hit me</a>
<div id="change" class="blah1"></div>
```

And JS Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#foo').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var changeDiv = $('#change'); 
        if ($(this).hasClass('two')) {
            changeDiv.addClass('blah2').removeClass('blah1');
            changeDiv.html('<p>Blah 2</p>');
        } else {
            changeDiv.addClass('blah1').removeClass('blah2');
            changeDiv.html('<p>Blah 1</p>');
        }
        $('.one').toggleClass('two');
    });
});
```

You will be able to toggle your link's class and change or update another div based on the class of your link when clicked.

You can see this code working at http://jsfiddle.net/PTdLQ/4/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is to check if the given class exists in the dom. Therefore, one can use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a#foo').click(function(){

        if ($('.two').length) {

            //there is a class two
            SomeFunction();   
        } else {

            //there is no class two
            SomeOtherFunction();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope I typed it right

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(!$('#mydiv').hasClass('myclass')) {
          $('#mydiv').addClass('myclass'); 
      }
});
</script>
```